# iOS Newsstand App: Download ePub

Tags: ios, ios5, epub

I want to develop an Newsstand application for the iPhone.

I know Apple recommends that the issue be downloaded as one file. Does Apple place any restrictions on how the magazine should be displayed to the reader? I would like to convert a client's mobile website into an epub, and display it in our app.

Is it possible to pass the app store guide line?

Comment: Newsstand is for periodical content. Why do you want to publish a mobile website as a magazine?

Comment: If you check out [Apple's Newsstand Page](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/newsstand/), they have: a) Guide Lines b) Video Tutorials c) Developer instructions d) etc. Check it out.